# React giving me Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, function, components, render, infinite-loop

The ***handleSortByChange*** function gives me an error on the browser stating that “Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.”  However, on the terminal, it indicates that ***compliled successfully***

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './SearchBar.css';

const sortByOptions = {
    'Best Match': 'best_match',
    'Highest Rated': 'rating',
    'Most Reviewed': 'review_count'
}

function SearchBar() {
    const [ sortBy, setSortBy ] = useState('best_match')

    const getSortByClass = (sortByOption) => {
        if(sortBy === sortByOption) {
            return 'active';
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    const handleSortByChange = (sortByOption) => {
        setSortBy(sortByOption);
    }

    const renderSortByOptions = () => {
        return Object.keys(sortByOptions).map((sortByOption) => {
            let sortByOptionValue = sortByOptions[sortByOption];
            return <li onClick={handleSortByChange(sortByOptionValue)} className={getSortByClass(sortByOptionValue)} key={sortByOptionValue}>{sortByOption}</li>
        })
    }

    return(
        <div className="SearchBar">
            <div className="SearchBar-sort-options">
                <ul>
                    {renderSortByOptions()}
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="SearchBar-fields">
                <input placeholder="Search Businesses" />
                <input placeholder="Where?" />
            </div>
            <div className="SearchBar-submit">
                {/* <a href="#">Let's Go</a> */}
                {/* <button>Let's Go</button> */}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: One thing you should be aware is that successful compilations / builds do not equate 0 runtime errors. Infinite loop rendering is a runtime error. React build processes have no way of knowing if your programming logic would render a component infinitely; at least that's true for the current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `<li>` tag you are directly calling the method like,

`onClick={handleSortByChange(sortByOptionValue)}`, which will set the state and rerender will be triggered, the same thing will happen again in this render cycle too, and thus the infinite loop.

instead do following:

```html
<li
          onClick={()=>handleSortByChange(sortByOptionValue)}
          className={getSortByClass(sortByOptionValue)}
          key={sortByOptionValue}
        >
```

in this way, the `handleSortByChange(sortByOptionValue)` will only get executed when the `<li>` element is clicked.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
// import './SearchBar.css';

const sortByOptions = {
  "Best Match": "best_match",
  "Highest Rated": "rating",
  "Most Reviewed": "review_count"
};

function SearchBar() {
  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState("best_match");

  const getSortByClass = sortByOption => {
    if (sortBy === sortByOption) {
      return "active";
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  };

  const handleSortByChange = sortByOption => {
    setSortBy(sortByOption);
  };

  const renderSortByOptions = () => {
    return Object.keys(sortByOptions).map(sortByOption => {
      let sortByOptionValue = sortByOptions[sortByOption];
      return (
        <li
          onClick={()=>handleSortByChange(sortByOptionValue)}
          className={getSortByClass(sortByOptionValue)}
          key={sortByOptionValue}
        >
          {sortByOption}
        </li>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="SearchBar">
      <div className="SearchBar-sort-options">
        <ul>{renderSortByOptions()}</ul>
      </div>
      <div className="SearchBar-fields">
        <input placeholder="Search Businesses" />
        <input placeholder="Where?" />
      </div>
      <div className="SearchBar-submit">
       
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ynsmt5)

Comment: in your original code, in ```<li/>``` onClick even, you are directly calling the function ```handleSortByChange(sortByOptionValue)```, as soon as the app is rendered, that function will execute and will change the state and trigger the next rerender, same thing happens in new rerender and the cycle continues.

Comment: in given solution we are doing ```<li onClick={()=>handleSortByChange(sortByOptionValue)}..```, where the ```handleSortByChange(sortByOptionValue)``` will not get executed until the click event is occurred.

Comment: Thank you so much. That makes so much sense!

Answer (score 1):

try this on the onClick function instead:

```
{() => onClick={handleSortByChange(sortByOptionValue)}
```